# PHPUnit: What happens to variables not addressed by the tearDown() method?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I would like to know whether the setting `null` to variables in the `tearDown` methods within `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` and children is **a mere formality** or serves some actual purpose.

Example:

```
protected function tearDown(){
  $this->someUsedVariable=null;
}
```

P.S.: I mean, don't used variables **get destroyed anyway** by the end of the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course they are destroyed at the end of the script. Once you started your test suite your script does not end directly, because you'll probably have hundrets or thousands of test cases being executed and all those test cases together will sooner or later use up all memory / fill up the max. number of connections to a database (etc.) if not properly teared down.

By setting variables to null you allow the garbage collector, once activated, to free up the used memory.

Comment: I see.. Do you by any chance run phpunit from zend studio? Mine is a little bit slow and I'd like to know whther it's just me or it happens to everyone

Comment: Haven't used phpunit for quite some time now (working with Ruby right now). You might wanna check xdebug and analyze whats talking so long.

Comment: PHPUnit holds on to a reference to every test case instance until all tests have completed and the final results have been printed. Setting test case instance variables to `null` allows the GC to delete them as long as no other variables hold references.

Answer (score 3):

the variables get destroyed after the end of the script.
tearDown can be helpful to delete the data produced during the test for examples, data in the database or generated files.